# Apache disable HTTPS redirect when URL contains certain path

Tags: apache

I have a virtual host config like this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well\-known/acme\-challenge/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/downloads/software/installer/
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://www.%1%{REQUEST_URI} [L,NE,R=301]
```

What I am trying to do is, when the URL is something like this:

`example.de/downloads/software/installer`

that it will not be redirected to HTTPS. It works, but not for the files in the folder or the subfolder.
So what must I change that all files and subfolder are accessible with HTTP?

Comment: ...exactly as you specify: There's not a single wildcard in the installer line (as is in the HTTP_HOST lines further down in your config)

Comment: how can I add a wildcard?

Comment: Why do you want to prevent https as you have described ?